# What is the chemical equation for cooking rice?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

What is the balanced chemical equation for the chemical reaction of cooking rice (including the formula for starch etc.)?

Comment: There really isn't a chemical formula for cooking rice.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially when rice is cooked all you are doing is adding water to it and heating it. No true chemical reaction occurs.  A way you could think of this addition of water in an equation is:
$$\ce{(C6H12O6)2 ->[\Delta][water] (C6H12O6)2.xH2O}$$
Not the most accurate representation as water was not added to a crystal system but I hope this helps you understand that no real reaction is occuring.

Comment: There might not be a simple equation but there is more to it than simple hydration. Surely there is some breakdown of the starchy component (starch being a long polymer of sugars)?